# can´t compare String values correctly

Tags: java, string, comparison

I´m having trouble with the while statement. I´ve narrowed it down to my use of the "!=", because if I try it with "==", then the program works, except opposite to how I want it to. What do I use to make it so that if the user types in "v", then it won´t display the user´s input, since there´s no such thing as "!==" :)

```
    Scanner scannerUi = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = scannerUi.nextLine();
    while (userInput != "v") {
        System.out.println(userInput);
        userInput = scannerUi.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: or towards left if your monitor is behind you and you are sitting with a mirror in front of you

Comment: Maybe they aren't an [ambiturner](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ambi-turner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
while (!userInput.equals("v")) {
        System.out.println(userInput);
        userInput = scannerUi.nextLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should always use equals() method for compairing the strings, because equals method examine the content and == method examine the references.

Comment: i never said that string is a primitives

Comment: other primitives can be converted to object by using wrapper class

Comment: i guess now it is clear

Answer (score 0):

I think that u need to compare string not on reference equality as u do it but on value equality.
So, if u want to compare your current string with some other (such as "v") just use:

```
userInput.equals("some_string")
```

Using "==" u will compare strings on reference equality, and using "equals()" u will compare strings on value equality